# how to add all received messages of reply queue to List

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I am publishing messages to request queue and getting those messages in reply queue. Here i want to further process the all received messages, so i want to add all the messages to List before sending to my processor(To do further operations).
Below is my code.

```
@Autowired
    private GeneralProcess generalProcess;

    List <RequestPojo> requestPojoGeneral = new ArrayList<RequestPojo>();

    @RabbitHandler
    @RabbitListener(containerFactory = "simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory", queues ="BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue")
    public void subscribeToRequestQueue(@Payload RequestPojo sampleRequestMessage, Message message) throws InterruptedException {


        requestPojoGeneral.add(sampleRequestMessage);
        System.out.println("List size issssss:" +requestPojoGeneral.size() );
        generalProcess.processRequestObjectslist(requestPojoGeneral);

        /*System.out.println("message in general listener is:" + sampleRequestMessage.getDistance());
        System.out.println("Message payload is:" + sampleRequestMessage);
        System.out.println("Message payload1111 is:" + message );*/

    }
```

The above code i am unable to get all messages at a time. I have to wait untill i get all the messages and populate list before calling  **generalProcess.processRequestObjectslist(requestPojoGeneral);**.Can any one suggest best way to wait calling processor method until get all messages and add  to list.

Thanks.

Comment: How will you determine that the list is complete and no more messages will arrive?

Comment: If we publish10 messages to request queue then the listener class will get those 10 messages . Then i want to add those 10 messages to list. I want to process this 10 messages together. After some time if we publish other 20 messages then i want to add those 20 to list and will process those. (As here listener will listen to reply queue when ever any thing published to request queue).

Comment: here i am processing CSV file and making pojo from CSV and publishing to request queue, if my CSV contain 10 records then want to process those 10 records as a chunk by publishing to request queue and by getting them in listener .

Answer (score 0):

You can add a header to the messages e.g. `messageCount`.

Then

```
if ((int) message.getMessageProperties().getHeader("messageCount") == list.size() {
    process();
}
```

(Or some other technique such as adding a header "lastMessage=true").

Bear in mind, if your server crashes before you get the full list, you will lose messages unless you set the acknowledgeMode to `MANUAL`.

Then, after you have processed all the messages, call `basicAck` on the Channel for the last message.

You can get access to the `Channel` as a method parameter and the deliveryTag is in the `MessageProperties`.

The container `prefetchCount` must be at least as big as your biggest batch because the broker will only allow that number of not-ack'd messages outstanding.

Comment: Russel Thank you very much!! i will try what you suggested.